# Javascript - pass variable by reference issue

Tags: javascript, operators, pass-by-reference

I am trying to make a copy of a javascript array and modify the 'copy' without modifying the original variable too, can anyone explain what I am doing wrong..

e.g

```
var array1 = [2, 5];
var array2 = '';

array2 = array1;
array2.pop();
console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);

// both output the same, however I want it to show array1 with 1 single item
```

I am trying to make it so `array2` will only contain the one item in the array & `array1` will contain two items in the array. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create a copy of an array rather than assign the reference value you can use the [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method.

```
array2 = array1.slice(0);
```

Slice returns a (shallow) copy of the given array from the given index to the (optional end index)

Comment: array2 = array1.slice(1); - this seems to work for me using 1 rather than 0, is that still correct (sorry for the noob questions) :)

Comment: @Zabs You don't have to apologize for asking questions :) That's what this site is for. if you use `.slice(1)` it returns a slice of `array1` not containing the element at position 0.

Comment: Thanks dude! +1 for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `slice()` to copy the array.

```
    var array1 = [2, 5];
    var array2 = '';

    array2 = array1.slice(0);
    array2.pop();
    console.log(array1);
    console.log(array2);
```

> slice does not alter the original array, but returns a new "one level
>   deep" copy that contains copies of the elements sliced from the
>   original array.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 0):

Alter the line `array2 = array1;` to:

```
array2 = array1.slice(0);
```

Slice method returns a (shallow) copy of the given array from the given index to the (optional end index)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as using the slice function:

```
var array1 = [2, 5];
var array2 = '';

array2 = array1.slice();
array2.pop();
console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

Here you are telling javascript to get a copy of the elements in array1 and assign the result to array2. By not setting the start and ending position it will slice the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

**When you writing this**

```
array2 = array1 //It creates reference on array1 object
array2.pop()  // removes 5 from both end
```

**So you have to clone one array to another by slice() method---**

```
array2 = array1.slice(0) // cloning array1 's  element  to array2
array2.pop() //  removes 5 from only array2 not from array1
```

**Now it works fine**

Comment: `array1` is a reference

Comment: No. `array2` and `array1` are both references (pointers to objects).

Comment: if i write array2=array1 that means,array2-->array1-->[2,5],so whenever we pop item from array2 that means it popped item from array1,thats why 5 is popped from both end

Comment: No. array2 --> [2,5] <-- array1. Like I told you, `array1` and `array2` are pointers to objects. Every value in JavaScript must be either a primitive or a pointer to an object. You fundamentally do not understand how values in JavaScript work.